# com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException (returned a response status of 400)

Tags: file-upload, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to set up file upload example using JAX RS. I could set up the project and successfully upload  file in a server location. **But i get the following error when file size is more than 10KB (weird!!)**

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: POST http://localhost:9090/DOAFileUploader/rest/file/upload returned a response status of 400
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:607)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:507)
at com.sony.doa.rest.client.DOAClient.upload(DOAClient.java:75)
at com.sony.doa.rest.client.DOAMain.main(DOAMain.java:34)
```

I am new to JAX RS and i'm not sure what exactly the issue is. Do i need to set some parameters client side or server side (like size, timeout etc)?

This is the client side code calling webservice:

```
public void upload() {
    File file = new File(inputFilePath);
    FormDataMultiPart part = new FormDataMultiPart();
    part.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("file", file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE));
    WebResource resource = Client.create().resource(url);
    String response = resource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(String.class, part);
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

This is the server side code:

```
@Path("/file")
public class UploadFileService {

@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    String uploadedFileLocation = "e://uploaded/"
            + fileDetail.getFileName();

    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}

private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        String uploadedFileLocation) {

    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                uploadedFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[16000];

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } } }
```

Please let me know what settings i have to change for file sizes greater than 10KB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload in a Jersey context, and it works fine., and yes, it set the max file size, sorry I missed this before.

here is a snipet of code I use (this is a multipart form, so there are other fields along with the file)

```
private LibraryUpload parseLibraryUpload(HttpServletRequest request) {
LibraryUpload libraryUpload;

File libraryZip = null;
String name = null;
String version = null;

ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);

FileItemIterator iter;
try {
  iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
while (iter.hasNext()) {
....
if (item.isFormField()) {
....
}else{
BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
      buffer.mark(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
      libraryZip = File.createTempFile("fromUpload", null);
      IOUtils.copy(buffer, new FileOutputStream(libraryZip));
...
}
```

Comment: Hi Samuel, I tried the code in writeToFile() method separately and it works fine. I am not sure what the prolem could be.

Comment: What version of Jersey do you use ? I do file upload, but my code is quite different, and I use jersey 1.12.

Comment: You can also replace  e.printStackTrace(); with some loggin AND return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build(); if this kind of error happens, might help understanding the issue

Comment: As your code seems ok to me, I can only recommend to switch to jersey 1.12, if possible for you, and throw the error 500 like said before if you catch an unexpected exception, and see what happens

Comment: Hi Samuel, The same problem with jersey 1.12. I believe the problem is while loading the file client side because for post request of file size greater than 10kb it is not entering the webservice method itself.

Comment: I have tried with both jersey client and httpclient. For both i get response status 400 bad request. The client code in my question is using jersey client.

Comment: I tried the same using spring. I had to set maxUploadSize in servlet.xml and it worked fine. In jersey is there anyway we can set upload size?

Comment: Hi, can i set proxy in jersey client?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem with Jersey. I have activated jersey trace but nothing help me.

I have changed the library by an apache Library and I see than the problem with linked to a repository for temporary files for tomcat. The repository was not exist. For files under 10k, the repository was not used.

So,  after the repository creation, I used jersey library and all works fine.